# Starting X without display manager

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, xorg, kde

I installed Arch with KDE Plasma. I want to start KDE without a display manager and configured files by following the instructions from [KDE - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE#From_the_console), but after configuring all that when I reboot it shows an error and I am back to tty1 with login screen.

```
(II) modset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24,8 bpc.
(II) modset(60): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8bpc.
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 51: twm: command not found
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 52: xclock: command not found
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 53: xterm: command not found
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 55: exec: xterm: not found
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 54: xterm: command not found
xinit: connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down (II) server terminated successfully (0). Closing log files.
```

My .xinitrc file

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"
fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi

twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login
export DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma
exec startplasma-x11
```

My .xserverrc file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp "$@" vt$XDG_VTNR`
```

My .bash_profile:

```
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
if [ -z "${DISPLAY}" ] && [ "${XDG_VTNR}" -eq 1 ]; then
   exec startx
 fi
```

All these files are in `/home/user` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what's wrong:

> Fatal server error:(EE) Unrecognised option: Vt1

Most things in Unix are case sensitive, in this case, you need to change your .xserverrc file to use the option `vt` (instead of `Vt`, note the lowercase `v`).

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp "$@" vt$XDG_VTNR`
```

Comment: Trapani Yeah, But after changing that I get another error. Posted Above.

Comment: I don't see any other error in your question ...

Comment: I should have commented after the edit, sorry!

Comment: That's another problem. Note that people here will gladly help with an issue, but will not walk you through a tutorial (that is actually off-topic). In this case though, your PATH is probably not set or you didn't install the software. Change `xterm` with the full path `/usr/bin/xterm` (or install `xterm` for example if you haven't). The same applies for the other *"not found"* errors. If the original issue was solved, then please mark this as solved (for those seeking help with the same error). And feel free to post a new question if something doesn't work, after you research the problem.

Comment: @ Eduardo Trapani , Thanks I solved the issue . It is ttwm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login should be removed from .xinitrc file so that it executes plasma.